# Formatting acronym in tableofcontent

Tags: table-of-contents, koma-script

I got a problem with my `\tableofcontents` command.

At first I post a simple example:

```
\documentclass[
  12pt,
  a4paper,
  DIV13,
  pdftex,     
  BCOR10mm,
  smallheadings,
  fleqn,
  liststotoc,
  bibtotoc,
  cleardoubleempty
  ] {scrbook}
 \usepackage{acronym}
  \begin{document}
    \tableofcontents 
    \section{Acronyms}
    \begin{acronym}[SQL]
     \acro{CMS}{Content Management System}
     \acro{SQL}{Structured Query Language}
     \acro{Bash}{Bourne-again shell}
    \end{acronym}
    \listoffigures 
    \listoftables
    \section{section1}
    blablabla \ac{CMS} blablabla
    \section{section2}
    blablabla \ac{SQL} blabla \ac{SQL}
\end{document}
```

My problem is now, that the Headline of Acronyms got the same style as section1. But I want the same style as `\listoffigures` in my `\tableofcontents` and in the rest of the document. Can anybody help me, please?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't you simply use a chapter instead of a section for including your acronyms?

You can use the `\addchap` command provided by KOMA classes to have an unnumbered chapter that is also shown in the ToC.

MWE

```
\documentclass[
  12pt,
  a4paper,
  DIV13,
  pdftex,
  BCOR10mm,
  headings=small,
  fleqn,
  listof=totoc,
  bibliography=totoc,
  cleardoublepage=empty
  ] {scrbook}
 \usepackage{acronym}
  \begin{document}
    \tableofcontents
    \addchap{Acronyms}
    \begin{acronym}[SQL]
     \acro{CMS}{Content Management System}
     \acro{SQL}{Structured Query Language}
     \acro{Bash}{Bourne-again shell}
    \end{acronym}
    \listoffigures
    \listoftables
    \chapter{chapter1}
    \section{section1}
    blablabla \ac{CMS} blablabla
    \section{section2}
    blablabla \ac{SQL} blabla \ac{SQL}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Note that I've also substituted some deprecated option with the new ones when loading `scrbook`.